# CHROME html radio to checkbox showing minus sign

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, checkbox

If you look at this code in chrome, the unselected checkboxes show as dashes, they should be empty, why is this?

HTML

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" >Red
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Blue
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Orange
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Green
</form>
```

CSS

```
input[type="RADIO"] {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yp5551Lq/)

Comment: it looks fine in my browser....

Comment: ya the same... lubuntu 12.04 with google-chrome-stable

Comment: can u post a screen shot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is consistent with the specs. This behaviour is being following from the 2004 System Appearance feature spec on system appearance.

This is because a `checkbox` can have an `indeterminate` state which is visual only and hence not controlled via CSS but can be manipulated via Javascript. Now, for a group of radios, only one can be checked at any time. Once one radio is checked, the others are unchecked. Until that happens, if the initial state is not marked in the markup, then their state is `indeterminate`.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/yp5551Lq/1/

You can notice that an `input[type=checkbox]` can have an `indeterminate` state which is visually represented by a `dash`. By the way, only `webkit` based browsers seem to support it. Firefox and IE seem to ignore the `appearance` property.

***Important:*** For `radio` styled as `checkbox`, this cannot be manipulated via Javascript. This is because, for `radio`s at least one is supposed to be `checked`. Unless, that happens it **will** be styled as `indeterminate`. The only solution for you is to set the `checked` attribute on one of the radios. Alternatively, you can have a hidden extra radio in the same group with its `checked` attribute set initially.

This spec is archived here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/User:Tantekelik/CR-css3-ui-20040511-appearance and the Source Ref: https://wiki.csswg.org/spec/css4-ui#appearance

The spec says:

> ...a button that displays whether or not it is checked with a small box
>   next to the button label.  There may be an 'x' or check mark inside
>   the box when the button is checked.  An indeterminate (neither checked
>   nor unchecked) state may be indicated with a dash '-' or a square or
>   some other graphic in the box.

So, the `webkit` based browsers use a `dash` to indicate `indeterminate` state.

***Snippet***:

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById("x");
checkbox.indeterminate = true;
```

```css
input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px; height: 24px;
}  
input[type="radio"] {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" >Radio 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Radio 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Radio 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="y" name="y">Checkbox 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="x" name="x">Checkbox 2<br>
```

Please note that interestingly, `appearance` is being dropped from the CSS 4 specs!

Comment: is it possible to set this with javascript to FALSE or something else which is not indeterminate?

Comment: Simple, as suggested by @zeee9, pre-check one of the radios.

Comment: @RafaTost: Added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hidden radio button and checked it

```
<label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="1" >Male</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="2">Female</label>
<input style="display: none;" type="radio" name="sex" value="0" checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to change, you have to select a default radio input.

Here I selected the first input:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked="checked" >Red
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Blue
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Orange
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Green
</form>
```

Comment: no, don't want to preselect for validation purposes