# How to remove line from checkbox?

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button

I am facing one problem. I have four radio button but i change its apperance with checkbox. they are actually radio button but look like checkbox . The problem is in google chrome. but working correct in firefox
Can anyone help me. here is my code:-

```css
input[type="radio"].custom-radio {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    -moz-appearance: checkbox;
    -ms-appearance: checkbox;     /* not currently supported */
    -o-appearance: checkbox;      /* not currently supported */
}
```

```html
<span class="text_part_class-2">
<span class="radio secondpart">
<input type="radio" value="Business for Sale" class="custom-radio" name="lastservice">
</span>
```

[image]

How do i remove the line from radio buttons but look like checkbox. THanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CHROME html radio to checkbox showing minus sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437414/chrome-html-radio-to-checkbox-showing-minus-sign)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
input[type="radio"].custom-radio {
-webkit-appearance: radio;
-moz-appearance: radio;
-ms-appearance: radio;     /* not currently supported */
-o-appearance: radio;      /* not currently supported */
```

}

Comment: i want radio button look like checkbox your css change my checkbox to radio please provide better solution

Comment: On this link you can find other solutions to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox