# shows customized tick, cross and minus sign icon in Checkbox using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

Customized tick, cross and minus sign in checkbox using CSS.

Note : not used any icon(ex : font awesome) or images.

Please help me.

I have attached image.

checkbox 3 states image
[image: checkbox 3 states image]

Comment: Provide  your code of what you have done till now.

Comment: Read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27437664/1355315

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
label.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {display:none;}
label.checkbox span {
  display:inline-block;
  border:2px solid #BBB;
  border-radius:10px;
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  background:#C33;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:3px;
  position: relative;
  transition:width 0.1s, height 0.1s, margin 0.1s;
}
label.checkbox :checked + span {
  background:#6F6;
  width:27px;
  height:27px;
  margin: 2px;
}
label.checkbox :checked + span:after {
  content: '\2714';
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 5px;
  color: #99a1a7;
}

<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <span></span>
  I like cake
</label>
```